# Methods to tell which type of regression to be used

Tags: regression, self-study, correlation, multiple-regression

> Given the total correlation coefficients between $X_1,X_2,X_3$, how can one determine whether to use Linear Regression or Multiple Regression when one is trying to predict $X_1$ from the others? If the person narrows on linear regression, it means she will use only one of $X_2$ or $X_3$ as the regressor. $r_{ij}$ denotes the correlation coefficient between $X_i$ and $X_j$ where $i,j\in\{1,2,3\}$.

I am given the following four situations:

1. $r_{23}=1$
2. $r_{23}=0$
3. $r_{23}=0,r_{12}=r_{13}$
4. $r_{12}=0.8,r_{13}=0.4,r_{23}=0.5$

I have to choose which type of regression I should use to predict $X_1$. My attempt is as follows. Please say if right or wrong.

1. $X_2,X_3$ are linearly related so even if we started with a Multiple Regression Equation, we would essentially boil down to a **linear regression** on either $X_2$ or $X_3$ as the regressor.
2. $X_2,X_3$ are uncorrelated, so intuitively **Multiple Regression** works. In fact, when I put in the corresponding correlation coefficients in the correlation matrix and try to obtain the multiple correlation coefficient $r_{1.23}=\sqrt{1-\dfrac{R}{R_{11}}}$ I find it is non-zero and well-defined. So multiple regression works. Besides the regression coefficients are not necessarily $0$. If however one of the correlation ceofficients $r_{12}$ or $r_{13}$ is $0$ then we are back to the linear regression model, otherwise not.
3. This is just a subset of the previous case. We should use **Multiple Regression** but in particular if $r_{12}=r_{13}=0$ then we have just got down to a situation where no variable explains anything about the other.
4. In this case, we use **Linear Regression** because I find the regression coefficient corresponding to $X_3$ is $0$ and hence $X_3$ gets out of the situation.

Are these arguments correct? Thanks!!

Comment: Model construction/choice should start with **substantive** thinkong, not with correlation coefficients! so tell us what is your variables, and which question you want an answer to. In language of the application.

Comment: The question is as written. I am given 4 situations and I have to select either linear regression or multiple regression. Which one should I choose and why?

Comment: I do not understand why the question got downvoted. The person who downvoted is requested to explain.

Comment: " I am given 4 situations". From whom? A book? A teacher? If not, and you gave yourself this four situations, please tell us from which practical application it came. I will remove the downvote as soon as we are given some real applied context.

Comment: Okay. Sorry if I was not clear. This is a first year undergrad semester exam question. Four cases are given and we have to say which regression, Linear or Multiple, will be suitable for each case.

Comment: The logic of this question is hard to understand, especially in part 4. That's where you basically already have performed a multiple regression in order to conclude that ordinary regression will suffice! In practice, because nobody (who is competent, anyway) would make modeling decisions using these kinds of criteria, the entire question is difficult to address. It's a bit like those infamous questions on medical board exams that describe a hypothetical patient and ask the examinee to select which of four different procedures is the best to use--when all four will kill the patient anyway.

Comment: Actually we have not yet been taught other methods of regression, and the question is aimed at first year Statistics undergrads so yeah !!